# Spark random forest indexoutofbounds exception when training

Tags: python, apache-spark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am attempting to run MLLIB's random forest model and am getting some out of bounds exceptions:

```
15/09/15 01:53:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (collect at DecisionTree.scala:977) finished in 0.147 s
15/09/15 01:53:56 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: collect at DecisionTree.scala:977, took 0.161129 s
15/09/15 01:53:57 INFO rdd.MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 4 from persistence list
15/09/15 01:53:57 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/random_forest/random_forest_spark.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/random_forest/random_forest_spark.py", line 121, in main
    trainModel(dset)
  File "/root/random_forest/random_forest_spark.py", line 136, in trainModel
    impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 352, in trainClassifier
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 270, in _train
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 128, in callMLlibFunc
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 121, in callJavaFunc
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.trainRandomForestModel.
: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1337 not in [0,1337)
        at breeze.linalg.SparseVector$mcD$sp.apply$mcD$sp(SparseVector.scala:74)
        at breeze.linalg.SparseVector$mcD$sp.apply(SparseVector.scala:73)
        at breeze.linalg.SparseVector$mcD$sp.apply(SparseVector.scala:49)
        at breeze.linalg.TensorLike$class.apply$mcID$sp(Tensor.scala:94)
        at breeze.linalg.SparseVector.apply$mcID$sp(SparseVector.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector$class.apply(Vectors.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.apply(Vectors.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$$anonfun$26.apply(DecisionTree.scala:992)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$$anonfun$26.apply(DecisionTree.scala:992)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$.findSplitsBins(DecisionTree.scala:992)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest$.trainClassifier(RandomForest.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainRandomForestModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:666)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I ran the sample python code [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/mllib-ensembles.html#examples) using data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt which ran correctly. However when I use my own RDD, I get the error described above. The format of my RDD entries are LabeledPoint from mllib while each labeled point's indicies are described by a mllib SparseVector. I am loading the data for the sparsevectors from a numpy csr matrix.

I didn't really see much of a difference from the sample loaded data and my own data. But I did notice that the error seems to always invoke on the last element of my RDD.

**Edit:**
Sample test case with my data trained on a random forest yielded the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.trainRandomForestModel.
: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1071 not in [0,1071)
```

I then tried looking more into my data with the following:

```
>>> dset = data.collect()
>>> dset[-1].features.size
1721
```

each entry is the following type:

```
>>> type(dset[-1].features)
<class 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector'>
```

The output of `dset[-1]` is of the form:

```
LabeledPoint(0.0, (2286,[44673,64508,65588,122081,306819,306820,382530,401432,465330,465336,505179,512444,512605,517844,526648,595536,595540,615236,628547,629226,810553,938019,1044478,1232743,... ... ...],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,... ... .. ]))
```

Note that the size of the number of features is the same is the error message's index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the reason I was getting these errors so I am posting it here in case someone else runs into it as well.

tl;dr I had the wrong value stored for SparseVector's size.

My instances of LabeledPoint objects for MLLIB hold `label` and `features`, where `features` should be a SparseVector object. This sparse object is declared using `SparseVector(vector_size, nonzero_indices, data)`.

However, I accidentally used number of nonzero values as `vector_size`. This can be seen in my example LabeledPoint output `LabeledPoint(0.0, (2286,[44673,64508, ...`

Here we can see that I declared my size as 2286, however even my first index (44673) is larger than my declared array size, thus causing me headaches.

Changing 2286 to the correct true non-sparse array size solved the problem

Comment: I've stucked with the same things, what does it mean changing to the correct non-sparse array size? 
Also you mentioned nonzero_indices - is that means indexes from 1 to N ?

Comment: So for example, if you have a vector (1,0,0,2,3) and you are using a sparse vector, the non-sparse array size is 5 since there are a total of 5 elements. nonzero_indices here would be (0,3,4) since those are the indices where there are none-zero numbers. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more important point to foboi1122's answer. Since the RDD of LabeledPoint contains collection of LabeledPoint, all these LabeledPoint should have the Vector_size as the (max index from all the LabeledPoint in the RDD) + 1. Addition of one is done because vector size is always one more than the max index in vector.

So basically you can not have these two LabeledPoint in the RDD.

*LabeledPoint (1.0,(29,[28],[32551.0])),*
*LabeledPoint (0.0,(12,[11],[18.0]))*

instead it should be

*LabeledPoint (1.0,(29,[28],[32551.0])),*
*LabeledPoint (0.0,(29,[11],[18.0]))*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).